# What online guides are there that can aid someone to start a forum roleplay?

Tags: online-resources, play-by-post

I am not sure if this is the right exchange to ask and I am not sure if the wording will be correct but here it goes.

I am quite fond of Post by Play forum roleplays where I can post whenever I feel inspired however my partner says that she had several negative experiences with them. As such as a gift from me to her I was planning to start a forum roleplay where it would be our world so that she felt like she could contribute and fix things that otherwise bugged her.

The setting itself is a fantasy setting that focuses on exploration with a small system similar to roll for shoes slapped into it to simulate character advancements(Lacking such a thing has always been one of the biggest problems for me in most places.)

Now while I have some experience playing in forum roleplays with an unified setting my experience is severely lacking when it comes to administrative department.

As to what I wish to ask(And I'm sorry for what appears to be a rant. I just wanted to clarify what kind of experience I have with forum roleplays,what I have in mind and for what purpose I am creating this.) I am in dire need of sources I can read in order to prepare an inclusive environment that doesn't feel toxic or overly restrictive so I'd like to know where I can read up on sources that can be of aid to me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is ultimately a 'shopping' question for resources. Asking for help in a forum or our [chat] may be better.

Comment: Having said that, I think it's quite reasonable to rewrite this asking for those with experience doing this to answer rather than outside resources.